# There is a pop-up showing "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect" in vscode while running python file

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

[[enter image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx7jA.png) here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNmw0.png)I tried a lot of solutions to slove this problem but couldn't solve it. There is a pop-up showing "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect" in vscode while running python file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjHxh.png)

Comment: What `launch.json` config are you using?

Comment: intergrated terminal

Comment: Please paste in the setting from `launch.json`. Working from an image is extremely difficult.

Answer (score 0):

there might be a problem with your connection. or more specifically, your python.exe's connection. if you have recently set a firewall or proxy or something, that might be the problem. that's what happened in my case